# GCP Cloud NAT Timeout Issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am facing some timeout issues when started using the GCP Cloud NAT. Earlier the instance was running with Static IP addresses but when I removed the static IP and started using Cloud NAT I am getting timeout after some time. Already tried to adjust the timeout setting in cloud NAT but it's not helping. Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

- It could be possible that your VM is running out of available
  [NAT-ports](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview#number_of_nat_ports_and_connections). CloudNAT’s ports per VM configuration is set to its
  default value 64 ports, which sometimes cause the VM to run out of
  NAT IP:Ports.
- During live operation, if the VMs + NAT run out of available ports
  due to open connections, you may begin to see dropped
  traffic/timeout. You may want to consider reducing the TCP timeout,
  or allocating more ports per VM. When you increase the **‘Minimum ports
  per VM instance’** on an existing Cloud NAT gateway, there is no
  interruption to traffic.
- I would suggest you modify the CloudNAT’s **‘Minimum ports per VM
  instance’** configuration to a greater value, maybe 5000 or more ports
  to sufficiently allow all connections to go through.
- You can see the current state of the NAT mapping (for example, number
  of ports per IP/VM) by using [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/routers/get-nat-mapping-info):

  ```
     gcloud compute routers get-nat-mapping-info [ROUTER NAME] --region=[REGION NAME]
  ```

For detailed information, you can check [here](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/ports-and-addresses#ports).

Answer (score 0):

its classic problem use GCP Cloud NAT, config "Minimum ports per VM instance" very torturous

AWS NAT GATEWAY easy to use with minimun config ready for high traffic website, but for GCP Cloud NAT you need add more IP Public and config "Minimum ports per VM instance" for GCP Cloud NAT